# Finding rolling z-score in Matlab

Tags: matlab, dataset

I want to calculate z-score of the current point in cross-sectional time-series data based on standard deviation over the last 10 days and simple moving average over the last 10 days. I can't use the z-score function in Matlab as it looks forward to calculate the z-score. Currently my solution is

```
for i=11:length(equity.(1))

 z(i) = (x(i)-mean(x(i-10:i))/std(x(i-10:i);

end
```

but issue is that i want to do this for the entire dataset at once. Is there a way to handle the entire matrix at once and calculate z-score for a given look back period (10 days in my case).

Answer (score 3):

Whether this is in fact more efficient or not I don't know, but one way (im2col requires the image processing toolbox):

```
data = 1:40; %dummy data
% presuming "ten days" means day of interest + 9 days back
n = 10;
data2 = im2col(data,[1,n],'sliding');

%mean/std for each column:
dmean = mean(data2);
dstd = std(data2); 

z = (data(n:end)-dmean)./dstd;
```

You might also try [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12550-slidefun-v4-0-sep-2008) from the file exchange.